# Azure AD SCIM client implementation - Users/Groups clarification

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, scim2

I am building a custom [SCIM client](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/app-provisioning/use-scim-to-provision-users-and-groups) that will be connected to Azure AD (using an Enterprise Application). I am only interested in user synchronization, I do not need group information.

> My question is if I only implement the `/User` endpoint and not the
> `/Group` endpoint, will the `/User` endpoint if the provisioning is
> done using groups (and not user) from the AAD portal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you assign a group containing users to the application in AAD but do not support /Groups, the provisioning job will still work fine. It will pull a list of all of the users that are members of the groups and use the group as a boundary for scoping what accounts are included in provisioning.